# Does the sequence $\frac{3^n}{n!}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $\frac{3^n}{n!}$ where $n$ varies from $1$ to $\infty$. Does the corresponding  series converge or diverge?

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n!}.
> $$

I reduced this to $(e^3 - 1)$. But how should I decide if this converges/diverges?

Comment: [The Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: If you are able to find a value for the sum, It means, It converges to that particular value!!

Comment: @WinVineeth Dont't tell that to someone who just discovered the "proof" that $\sum n = -\frac1{12}$.

Answer (score 2):

## Good news!

You have already solved the problem.

As you correctly note, this is $e^3 - 1$.

That's because the series for $e^x$ converges everywhere! So you are done, it **converges** (specifically to $e^3 - 1$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{3^n}{n!}$ converges to $e^3$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$,

$\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{3^n}{n!}-1$ converges to $e^3-1$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$

That is $\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{3^n}{n!}$ converges to $e^3-1$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: if $a_m \rightarrow a$, we know that $a_m-1 \rightarrow a-1$ right?

Here, $a_m=\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{3^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 0):

When saying that you have 'reduced it' to $e^3 -1$ - which none the less is correct and thus the series converges to that particular value - you most likely used that $e^x = \sum_n x^n/n!$, which luckily converges everywhere, so you are allowed to evaluate it for $x = 3$; Unlike the series $\sum_n x^n$ which cannot be evaluated for e.g. $x = 3$. But by just stating that the series expansion for $e^x$ converges for every $x$, you have already solved the problem!

Since you ask of convergence, to find the convergence radius, use the ratio test as suggested;

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left \lvert \frac{x^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{x^n/n!}\right \rvert = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{n+1} = 0 < 1, \quad \forall x\in \Bbb{R},
$$
so in particular, the series for $e^x$ converges for $x = 3$.

Answer (score -2):

If for all n, n not equals 0, then the following rules apply:
Let L = lim (n -- > inf) | an+1 / an |.
If L < 1, then the series sum (1..inf) an converges.
If L > 1, then the series sum (1..inf) an diverges.
If L = 1, then the test in inconclusive.
Here the limit lim (n -- > inf) | an+1 / an |. Is Zero. hence the series is converging.
This is the ratio test.

Comment: Can someone say,......why is this answer downvoted..... the answer is logical and correct as well

Comment: I do not know who down voted, but I can give some reasons - 1) No Latex, so difficult to understand. 2) Better and similar answers presented already

Comment: then upvote others ..... why downvotemine

Comment: You can learn quickly how to type maths with LaTeX in this forum in [this link.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thnxxx :) for the link